# Object being received as null from form POST

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am trying to call a URL to convert an object into an excel file to be downloaded by the client, so I am using the following HTML:

```
<form id="downloadAsExcelForm" style="display: none;" action="global/DownloadFile" method="POST">
    <input id="downloadToken" type="hidden" name="token" value="" />
    <input id="complexObject" type="hidden" name="complexObject" value="" />
</form>
```

Along with the following JavaScript:

```
var req = {
param1: "Example",
param2: 1,
param3: [ { attr1: "test", attr2: 1, attr3: "Hello" },
    { attr1: "test", attr2: 1, attr3: "Hello" },
    { attr1: "test", attr2: 1, attr3: "Hello" }  ]
};

$("#downloadToken").val("nhwe1-jdw3e-djdw2-mkcds");
$("#complexObject").val(JSON.stringify(req));
$("#newQueryForm").submit();
```

And finally, the following Controller .cs:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string token, wcfGlobal.complexObjectRequest complexObject)
{ 
    ...
}
```

The problem I am having is that the token is being received just fine (it is just a simple string); however, the `complexObject` is being received as null.

Does anyone know how I could resolve this issue? I usually just use `jQuery.ajax(...)` for these types of requests, but given that I need to download the file directly, I don't have that option here.

Comment: The controller is of type `Controller` (e.g. MVC) or `ApiController`?

Comment: @TasosK. Oops, it's of type Controller

Comment: I should probably mention that there are arrays of object being sent as well. I've updated the .js portion to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing the `req` object before sending it, so it is sent as a string. There is not a way to automatically have the `complexObject` deserialized.

The way I see it you can keep sending the complex object as string and deserialize it in the controller

**HTML**

```
<form id="downloadAsExcelForm" style="display: none;" action="global/DownloadFile" method="POST">
    <input id="downloadToken" type="hidden" name="token" value="" />
    <input id="complexObject" type="hidden" name="complexObjectStr" value="" />
</form>
```

**C#**

```
// Required reference
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public ActionResult DownloadFile(string token, string complexObjectStr)
{
    wcfGlobal.complexObjectRequest complexObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<wcfGlobal.complexObjectRequest>(complexObjectStr);

    // Now complexObject has the values you sent from the browser
}
```

Based on the JavaScript you posted the `complexObjectRequest` class needs to be declared like this

```
public class complexObjectRequest
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public int param2 { get; set; }
    public List<Param3> param3 { get; set; }

    public complexObjectRequest()
    {

    }
}

public class Param3
{
    public string attr1 { get; set; }
    public string attr2 { get; set; }
    public string attr3 { get; set; }

    public Param3()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I was being a dummy. Thanks for the help! By the way, do you know how jQuery's ajax method passes objects to webservices? And if there's any way to do so with forms?

Comment: Glad I helped! When you say webservices, you mean `.asmx`? If so, see [this post](http://codehandbook.org/call-asmx-web-service-from-jquery-ajax/) on how to call them with jQuery ajax. On the part on how to call them with forms, I an mot sure how this would work, since a plain HTTP POST has `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` where the `.asmx` expects `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: I see what you mean. That makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The complexObjectStr variable should be a string because after you use stringify function, this value is string (not a object). 
And in your action (in controller), you have to Deserialize that string to wcfGlobal.complexObjectRequest.